# Is there a PubSubHubbub Server implementation in java?

Tags: websub

Is there a PubSubHubbub Server not publisher implementation in java?

Comment: Have you tried to ask google with "PubSubHubbub java"? I get matches...

Comment: I meant the hub server implementation in java not the client side (publisher or subscriber)

Answer (score -2):

Check [this](https://github.com/berb/java-sub-pubsubhubbub) out. A straight-forward subscriber implementation written in Java for the PubSubHubBub 0.3 protocol.

Usage:

```
Subscriber subscriber = new SubscriberImpl("subscriber-host",8888);
Subscription subscription = subscriber.subscribe(URI.create("http://feed-host/my-push-enabled-feed.xml"));

subscription.setNotificationCallback(new NotificationCallback()
{

    @Override
    public void handle(SyndFeed feed)
    {
        //TODO: Do something with the feed
    }
} );
```

Comment: Do you know a hub server (not the publisher) implementation in java?

Comment: Have you checked http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub-java/ ? and https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/

Comment: code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub-java has only publisher and subscriber not the hub. From the wiki  https://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/wiki/Hubs,  it doesn't have java implementation of hub